# Swift Firebase Append Image for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need help appending a image I downloaded from firebase so I can use it to be share over the UIActivityViewController. I get the right image but unsure how to set up the data pass to let it be shared. The current set up throws a "Thread 1 error" on "objectsToShare = [self.image!]".

```
let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        var objectsToShare: [AnyObject]?


        let titlePost = self.feeds[sender.tag].downloadURL

        if let postURL = URL(string: titlePost) {
            let postRequest = URLRequest(url: postURL)
            self.image?.setImageWith(postURL, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (imageRequest, imageResponse, error) -> Void in
                // failure downloading image
                print("Error downloading Firebase post image")
                print(error)
            })
        }

        objectsToShare = [self.image!]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare!, applicationActivities: nil)

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of the below:

```
objectsToShare = [self.image!]
```

You have to use like this :

```
 if let image = self.image {
      objectsToShare.append(image)
 }
```

Comment: getting "objectsToShare" as nil. Maybe I am not downloading the image correctly?

Comment: It will take some time to load the image right. At the time you are assigning the image, may be it’s not downloading. So move that code to completion block and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what a completion handler is first.

You should check for error in the completion, and if there's not, do what you have to do with your image. As the request is asynchronous the image isn't there yet on the line just after.
Do something like that :

```
self.image?.setImageWith(postURL, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (imageRequest, imageResponse, error) -> Void in
    // This closure is called when the request is done
    if error == nil {
        objectsToShare = [self.image!]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare!, applicationActivities: nil)
        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // failure downloading image
        print("Error downloading Firebase post image")
        print(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: You might wanna re-check your answer. Lots of errors.

Comment: Check it now, I did duplicate 2 lines. If there's still errors, it's coming from your code cause I only copy paste it and rearranged it. I explained what you should do so it should be enough even for a beginner developer

Comment: I get this warning for "if error == nil " "Comparing non-optional value of type 'SDImageCacheType' to nil always returns false"

Comment: Meaning, no result. No success or fail.